# Does a useful Haskell HashMap/HashTable/Dictionary library exist?

Tags: haskell, hashmap, hashtable, asymptotic-complexity, hackage

I'm looking for a monad-free, constant access query *O(1)* associative array.

Consider the hypothetical type:

```
data HT k v = ???
```

I want to construct an immutable structure once:

```
fromList :: Foldable t, Hashable k => t (k,v) -> HT k v
```

I want to subsequently query it repeatedly with constant time access::

```
lookup :: Hashable k => HT k v -> k -> Maybe v
```

There appears to be two candidate libraries which fall short:

- [`unordered-containers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers)
- [`hashtables`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables)

#### `unordered-containers`

`unordered-containers` contains both strict and lazy variants of the type `HashMap`. Both `HashMap`s have *O(log n)* queries as documented by the [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.7.1/docs/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html#v:lookup) function. This query access time appears to be due to the construction of the `HashMap` types, which have an internal tree structure allowing for *O(log n)* [`insert`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.7.1/docs/Data-HashMap-Lazy.html#v:insert) functionality. An understandable design trade off for many use-cases, but since I don't need a mutable `HashMap` this tradeoff hampers my use-case.

#### `hashtables`

`hashtables` contains a `HashTable` type-class and three instance types with varying table constructions strategies. This library's type-class defines a constant time *O(1)* [`lookup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashtables-1.2.1.0/docs/Data-HashTable-Class.html#v:lookup) function definition, but it is eternally embedded in the `ST` monad. There is no way to "freeze" the stateful `HashTable` implementations and have a `lookup` function that is not embedded of a stateful monad. The library's type-class interface is well designed when the entire computation is wrapped in a state monad, but this design is unsuitable for my use-case.

---

Does there exist some other library which defines types and functions which can construct an immutable constant access query *O(1)* associative array that is not embedded in a stateful monad?

Does there exist some way to wrap or modify these existing hashing-based libraries to produce an immutable constant access query *O(1)* associative array that is not embedded in a stateful monad?

Comment: First off: I believe that you are correct.  There is no pure + O(1) lookup key-value structure.  OTOH, the first question that comes up is one of necessity.  Avoiding monads (including avoiding using IO) is sort of an aesthetic choice that often lacks technical justification - in this case that avoidance is at an obvious cost.  Similarly, the suspicious of premature optimization has already been raised.  If you are so inclined then please do consider a patch to the `hashtables` library that adds a freeze operation and pure lookup.  Or try a HashMap and see if the performance concretely.

Comment: @ThomasM.DuBuisson I was using a matrix of `(i,j)` keys for *O(1)* queries, but the matrix's dimensions grow far to quickly and the matrix is a sparsely populated upper triangular matrix. The memory requirements were not scalable. I was quite shocked when I couldn't find a suitable hashtable structure to replace the lookup matrix. There is a [feature request](https://github.com/gregorycollins/hashtables/issues/35) for freezing `HashTable`, but it is unanswered and I'm not able to construct a pull request at this time.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The library you want is… `unordered-containers`. Or just plain old `Data.Map` from `containers`, if you’d prefer.

The note in the [`unordered-containers` documentation](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers-0.2.7.1/docs/Data-HashSet.html) explains why you shouldn’t worry about the *O*(log *n*) time complexity for lookups:

> Many operations have a average-case complexity of *O*(log *n*). The implementation uses a large base (i.e. 16) so in practice these operations are constant time.

This is a common practice with certain kinds of functional data structures because it allows good sharing properties while also having good time complexities. log<sub>16</sub> still produces *very small* numbers even for very large *n*, so you can almost always treat those complexities as “effectively constant time”.

If this is ever a bottleneck for your application, sure, go with something else, but I find that highly unlikely. After all, log<sub>16</sub>(1,000,000) is a little under 5, so your lookup time is not going to grow very quickly. Processing all that data is going to take up much more time than the overhead of the lookup.

As always: profile first. If you somehow have a problem that absolutely needs the fastest possible hash map in the world, you might need an imperative hash map, but for every case I’ve ever had, the functional ones work just fine.

Comment: I didn't read the header documentation for `unordered-containers`'s `HashMap` type, only the documentation for the `lookup` function so I missed the information you referenced about a large log base. I'll try using the `HashMap` type and profile the performance.

Answer (score 11):

You should follow Alexis' suggestion and use `unordered-containers`. If you really want something that is guaranteed to have `Θ(1)` `lookup`s, you can define your own frozen version of any of the hash table types from `hashtables` using `unsafePerformIO`, but this is not very elegant. For example:

```
module HT
    ( HT
    , fromList
    , lookup
    ) where

import qualified Data.HashTable.IO as H
import Data.Hashable (Hashable)
import Data.Foldable (toList)
import System.IO.Unsafe (unsafePerformIO)
import Prelude hiding (lookup)

newtype HT k v = HT (H.BasicHashTable k v)

fromList :: (Foldable t, Eq k, Hashable k) => t (k, v) -> HT k v
fromList = HT . unsafePerformIO . H.fromList . toList

lookup :: (Eq k, Hashable k) => HT k v -> k -> Maybe v
lookup (HT h) k = unsafePerformIO $ H.lookup h k
```

Both uses of `unsafePerformIO` above should be safe. For that is crucial that the `HT` is exported as an abstract type.

Comment: Rather than `fromList` as a primitive, you could use `runHT :: (forall s. ST s (HashTable s k v)) -> HT k v`.

Answer (score 2):

> Does there exist some other library which defines types and functions which can construct an immutable constant access query O(1) associative array that is not embedded in a stateful monad?

At this point in time, the answer is still no.

As of late-2019 there is an efficient `IO`-based [`hashtable`](https://lowerbound.io/blog/2019-10-24_concurrent_hash_table_performance.html) package with decent benchmarks.

What you describe seems doable in the same way that pure, immutable [`Data.Array`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/array/docs/Data-Array.html) construction is possible. See [`Data.Array.Base`](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/packages/array/blob/master/Data/Array/Base.hs) for how this is achieved via `unsafe*` operators. A `Data.Array` is defined with a bound, and my initial thought is that a pure, immutable hashtable will potentially have GC problems if it's allowed to grow without bounds.